# Combining swipe down and long press

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement in my ViewController( which has a tableView) two gesture recognisers that have to work one after another. The first one is a swipe down gesture and the second a long press gesture.

Here's my code modified with @sergio suggestions

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        swipeDown = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDownAction)] autorelease];

        longPress = [[[CustomLongPress alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressAction)] autorelease];


        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2;

        swipeDown.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;


       swipeDown.delegate = self ;

        longPress.delegate = self ;

        [myTableView addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];

        [myTableView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];





  }


    -(void)swipeDownAction {

        _methodHasBeenCalled = YES;    // bool @property declared in .h

        NSLog(@"Swipe down detected");


    }



    -(void)longPressAction {

        NSLog(@"long press detected");
    }

    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
    {
        return YES;
    }
```

And my UILongPressGestureRecognizer subclass:

```
#import "CustomLongPress.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface CustomLongPress()
{

    ViewController *vc;
}

@end


@implementation CustomLongPress
-(id)initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action controller:(ViewController *)viewCon
{
    self = [super initWithTarget:target action:action];

    if (self) {

        vc = viewCon;

    }

    return self;
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     NSLog(vc.methodHasBeenCalled ? @"Yes" : @"No");

    if (vc.methodHasBeenCalled) {

        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I still get only the log from swipeDown but no log when it comes to longPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to create you own custom gesture recognizer. The best way would be for you to subclass `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and make it "accept" the long press only after the swipe has ended. E.g., in the `touchesBegan` method

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
   <if swipe recognizer action method has been called>
       [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
   }
}
```

In this way, both gesture recognizers would try to recognize the gesture: the swipe recognizer would do so immediately; while the custom recognizer would "wait" for the swipe recognizer to have fired.

An easy way to implement the condition `<if swipe recognizer action method has been called>` would be setting a global flag in your swipe action (you set it when the swipe action is executed; then the custom recognizer reads its value). This is *easy*, by far not the best implementation you can find.

Another approach would be relying on the `requiresGestureRecognizerToFail` to chain 3 standard gesture recognizers, let's call them A, B, and C, where:

1. A is a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`;
2. C is a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`;
3. B is any gesture recognizer.

You configure them like this:

```
C --> B --> A
```

whereby `x --> y` denotes that `x` requires `y` to fail. Thus, you would have that `C` (your long press gesture recognizer) will require the `B` GR to fail and `B` requires `A` (your swipe recognizer) to fail; `B` will fail as soon as `A` will recognized the swipe; once `B` fails, `C` will be allowed to recognize the long press if any.

EDIT:

after reading your comment, would you mind trying this and see if it helps out:

1. remove your overridden `touchesBegan` and replace it by:

   ```
   - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
   }
   ```
2. then define:

   ```
   - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

     if (vc.methodHasBeenCalled) {
       [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
     } else {
        return;
     }
   }
   ```

If this does not work, then make your custom gesture recognizer inherit from a generic gesture recognizer and

1. leave `touchesBegan:` in place and replace `touchesMoved` with:

   ```
   - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

     self.lastTouch = [touches anyObject];
     if (vc.methodHasBeenCalled && self.gestureNotBegunYet == YES) {
       self.gestureNotBegunYet = NO;
       [self performSelector:@selector(recognizeLongPress) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

     } else {
        return;
     }
   }
   ```

and add:

```
- (float)travelledDistance {
  CGPoint currentLocation = [self.lastTouch locationInView:self.view.superview];
  return sqrt(pow((currentLocation.x - self.initialLocation.x), 2.0) +
            pow((currentLocation.y - self.initialLocation.y), 2.0));
}

- (void)fail {
  self.gestureNotBegunYet = YES;
  [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

}

- (void)recognizeLongPress {

  if ([self travelledDistance] < kTapDragThreshold) {
    self.longPressed = YES;
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;
  } else {
        [self fail];
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
  }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
  [self fail];
  [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
  [self fail];
  [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

You will need to define in `.h`

```
@property(nonatomic) CGPoint initialLocation;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITouch* lastTouch;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL gestureNotBegunYet;
```

Comment: I will try this , much obliged !

Comment: also check my edit for an alternative approach, more contrived if you like but without subclassing.

Comment: is `@interface CustomLongPress()` correct? you left the base class out... are you getting `touches began` traces?

Comment: yes, the log from touchesBegan is being shown and `@interface CustomLongPress` is correct

Comment: ok, then, what is `vc.methodHasBeenCalled` when you get in touchesBegan? would you add its value to the NSLog trace?

Comment: i have traced my bool and when entering `touchesBegan` the value is NO so  `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]` does not get called because the bool should be YES in order for swipe down to be detected and therefore triggering the long press... what should I do ?

Comment: you said that you get the log from `swipeDown`, so at some point the swipe recognizer was firing correctly. That is the place where `vc.methodHasBeenCalled` is set, so it should be also true in `touchedBegan`. When is touchesBegan fired? before or after the swipe recognizer is recognized?

Comment: yes I get the log  from swipe down but after that nothing ; touchesBegan from my custom class is fired up only if I erase the if condition and when I execute on the screen only the longPress. If my code remains as it is touchesBegan never fires.

Comment: sorry,ignore my last comm ! touchesBegan is fired , before my swipe is recognized.When I begin doing the swipe, first I get in the output the value NO from touchesBegan and immediateley after this , the swipe down action log.

Comment: please, see my edit. Hope you can work it out from there... BTW, possibly, it would have been better to subclass `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and then start the LongPress from its action method...

Comment: thank you very much , manage to solve it only with `touchesMoved`  happy new year with lots of code :D

Comment: glad it worked. happy new year to you as well and let´s hope that at least some of it is *paid* code! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, once the system has detected a specific kind of gesture (tap, swipe, pan, long press, etc.) it can no longer send different types of gestures for that touch action.

This does not prevent you from achieving your desired results.  Perhaps with a combination of overloading the following `UIResponder` methods:

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

And using a gesture recognizer (not sure if the input will be consumed by one and ignored by the other), you could determine that it is a "long swipe"